# How can a ruby method not repond_to a method but also call the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm working with a little method that checks to see if a Tenant has a feature enabled. Each Tenant has a TenantPlan which stores the flags. I also have some flags on the Tenant model that can be used to override the plan-specific flags. A little feature detect method looks like this on the Tenant model:

```
def has_feature?(feature, feature_default = false)
  if tenant_plan
    feature = "#{feature}_enabled?".to_sym
    return tenant_plan.send(feature) || (respond_to?(feature) and send(feature))
  end
  feature_default
end
```

The part I'm most interested in for this question is this:

```
(respond_to?(feature) and send(feature))
```

I'm checking if a field of the same name exists on the Tenant model and getting the result of that if it does.

If I use console to check this out:

```
[1] pry(main)> false and tenant.send(:free_courses_enabled?)
=> false

[2] pry(main)> true and tenant.send(:free_courses_enabled?)
NoMethodError: undefined method `free_courses_enabled?' for #<Tenant:0x007f8f7171d6c8>
from /Users/typeoneerror/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@doki/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

I would expect the `send` to not even get called if Tenant does not `respond_to?` the feature method, which is what looks like is happening in the console tests, but I'm finding in my tests that even when `respond_to?` returns false, send is called but no `NoMethodError` is raised.

```
expect(tenant).not_to receive(:free_courses_enabled?)
```

result:

```
expected no Exception, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<Tenant:0x007fdfd908a2a8>).free_courses_enabled?(no args)
           expected: 0 times with any arguments
           received: 1 time> with backtrace:
```

Somewhat hilariously, when I expect the opposite:

```
expect(tenant).to receive(:free_courses_enabled?).and_call_original
```

We get

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `free_courses_enabled?' for #<Tenant:0x007f8254bfedd8>
```

I'm at a loss.

Does ruby swallow the `NoMethodError` exception in this case while calling the method since the first part of the expression returns false? Would appreciate an explanation and happy to hear any advice on rewrites.

It's looking to me like a RSpec bug with ActiveModel. When I don't add the expectation and when I run code in development it acts as expected.

Comment: So at this point, I'd double-check all the small underlying assumptions... even if you know they should hold. In your console... can you try `tenant.respond_to?(:free_courses_enabled?)` also try `tenant.respond_to?("free_courses_enabled?")` (you know you can use a string, you don't need to to_sym it right?) in your `has_feature?` method I'd try *not* to_symming it... I'd also try not overloading the variable-name `feature` (in case it's some weird scoping error) eg: `feature_method = "#{feature}_enabled?"` and `respond_to?(feature_method) && send(feature_method)`

Comment: also try `puts " do I respond to method: #{feature_method.inspect} ? #{respond_to?(feature_method)}"` to check you're trying what you think you're trying and getting the response you think you are...

Comment: But finally... yes... ruby defines the `respond_to?` set ever-so-slightly-differently to the set of methods that will actually not explode if you try to `send` to them... so there is a chance that you really are getting different results (mostly this'll happen if you're using `method_missing` to define the method)

Comment: @TarynEast thanks for the advice! I tried everything you suggested and they all return false (do I respond to method: "free_courses_enabled?" ? false), yet it still seems to actually "send" the method according to rspec. so it's either weirdness of rspec mocking or respond_to? might do something fancy. I'm not super worried about it. Code does what I want.

Comment: heh, yeah that is weird... I wonder if, beneath the covers `respond_to?` is doing something super-odd... like trying to send and then catching the `NoMethodError` exception (as you mentioned) :P I would have thought it would have just checked the internal array of method-names...

Comment: Checking the source code: http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F no, it's not doing it the try-catch way (which is good)

Comment: In your has_feature? method, why are you using `|` and not `||`? Are you trying to use bitwise "or" instead of regular "or"?

Comment: @maxple I am using ||, that was an experiement

Comment: @TarynEast I'm  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/respond_to%3F. The override here is where it's going off the rails.

Comment: So I guess the next relevant question might be... where/how do you define your `"#{feature}_enabled?"` methods?

Comment: @TarynEast boolean database fields. Rails creates name_enabled, name_enabled?, and name_enabled=, so I was assuming I could check if name_enabled? was defined. I get a different result with "name_enabled" and "name_enabled?" so I think there's something there.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a bg. When you write this `expect(tenant).not_to receive(:free_courses_enabled?)` rspec has to create a method on your object to test whether it has been called or not, so when your code runs then it finds the method to be defined. You might have to stub `respond_to?` to get the result you are expecting.

Comment: @MarcRohloff Yes, you are correct. Took me a while to figure that out. Answered the question with my findings below. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out after running my head into various libraries. `Tenant` does not define a method called `payment_options_features?`, so when I go into the console and do:

```
tenant.respond_to?(:payment_options_features?) # false
```

However, I believe my expectation that tenant should not receive the method in my RSpec test...

```
expect(tenant).not_to receive(:payment_options_features?)
```

actually *creates* a mock of that function on the tenant object, so when the test runs:

```
tenant.respond_to?(:payment_options_features?) # true
```

Because it's "mocked". The alternative is to do this instead since we know `send` is a method that should always exist.

```
expect(tenant).not_to receive(:send).with('payment_options_features?')
```